# Return Code of JCL in SAS is it possible?

Tags: sas, mainframe, jcl

i heared that JCL returtn code always have the highest return value.
ex:

```
when step 1 ends with 1 
step ends with 0
step3 ends with 0
```

when i want to execute step4 and the return value from the JCL(maximum code which is 1 in the example cae) has to be sent to SAS code which is called from stp 4 for processing
is it possible?

can any one help me !!!!

Comment: You should include a `mainframe` tag as this is something specific to Mainframe SAS (indeed, the resolution probably doesn't have much to do with SAS)

Comment: Return Codes are at step level. A job will report a highest Return Code. The short answer to your question is No. You can't magically pass the highest Return Code, or Return Code from a previous step, to a program just with JCL. The longer answer is Yes, it will probably be possible to do what you want, however you have asked us how to provide the solution you have come up. If you let us know what you are attempting to do, you may get some suggestions. So edit your question with any details we may need. We don't know what you want, we know one way you can't do what you want.

Comment: As Bill stated it is not possible to pass a return code from JCL to your SAS program. What he is asking for is why you want to pass the return code to SAS, What is SAS going to do with the RETURNCODE ???there is probably a way to achieve what you want if you tell us.

Answer (score 4):

As Bill stated you **can not pass a return code** from a previous step to a program in JCL.

Bill is asking **why** you want to pass the return code to your program

Options you have include:

- Using the JCL **if** statement see [JCL IF examples](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r11/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r11.ieab600/iea2b690635.htm) or **cond** option basically:

  ```
  // IF (RC = 1) THEN
  //     EXEC PGM=MyProg,PARM='1'
  // END-IF
  // IF (RC = 2) THEN
  //     EXEC PGM=MyProg,PARM='2'
  // END-IF
  // IF (RC = 3) THEN
  //     EXEC PGM=MyProg,PARM='3'
  // END-IF
  // IF (RC > 3) THEN
  //     EXEC PGM=MyProg,PARM='99'
  // END-IF
  ```

  or

  ```
  //     EXEC PGM=MyProg,PARM='1',cond=(0,ne)
  //     EXEC PGM=MyProg,PARM='2',cond=(1,ne)
  //     EXEC PGM=MyProg,PARM='3',cond=(2,ne)
  //     EXEC PGM=MyProg,PARM='99',cond=(4,lt)
  ```
- update the previous programs and write to file rather than issueing a return code.
- You could run **rexx** script background and call the programs from rexx. In rexx
  you can call a program and save the return code then pass it to a subsequent program. This should be viewed as a last resort though